# How to manage multiple mice and keyboards with pygame?

Tags: python, count, keyboard, pygame, mouse

Here is my question: how to manage multiple mice and keyboards with pygame ?

I am new on pygame but not on python.
Currently, I know how to manage one mouse and one keyboard with respectively pygame.mouse and pygame.key modules. I even know how to manage multiple joysticks with the pygame.joystick module. But sadly, it seems that there is no way to count how many mice and keyboards there are like pygame.joystick.get_count() does for joysticks. I also tried to look at the pygame.event module: there is an event.type for joystick id but there is no event.type for mouse id or a keyboard id... so now I am afraid I am blocked :/
Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: AFAIK, the OS treats all mice as one mouse. In the end, you just get a pointer coordinate, and there is always only one pointer. Same goes for keyboard - OS tells you key "x" was pressed, but not on which keyboard.

Comment: So it's more about how the computer works than pygame ? It's a pity than we can not plug and play with several mice and keyboards on the same device... but anyway there are still joysticks!

Comment: Well, I would say that it should be theoretically possible to implement your own keyboard and mouse drivers which provide the wanted behaviour, but it is probably not worth the trouble ;)

Answer (score 0):

What zvone said

> AFAIK, the OS treats all mice as one mouse. In the end, you just get a pointer coordinate, and there is always only one pointer. Same goes for keyboard - OS tells you key "x" was pressed, but not on which keyboard.

is certainly true, but there are easy workarounds which allow the OS recognize 2 separate keyboard inputs. I don't think, however, that there is an easy workaround the fact that [pygame.KEYDOWN](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) event only recognizes the key pressed, meaning that the library definately cannot distinguish between two keyboards. In some cases that's fine, for example when you want to type on both keyboards, most of the time you can get away with treating both of the keyboards as the same one. In games that is not the case. I don't think this library is suited to deal with this problem.

P.S.: Would leave this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation to do that...

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [small library](https://github.com/holl-/win-raw-in) to hook raw mouse and keyboard events in Windows. This should also work with PyGame.

```
hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
winrawin.hook_raw_input_for_window(hwnd, raw_event_handler)
```